# How to pass Rails file_field default value for ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile with CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

My Rails application show confirmation page when user edit own profile.
The confirmation page is just hide the form and set users input values as default values.

```
<%= @user.name %>
<%= image_tag @uer.image_url if @user.image? %>
-# hidden by css
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

However since not to be able to set default value for file_field, cannot update image column. Is there any good way to set or pass uploaded file?

Comment: Why do you need this form when it's hidden?

Comment: To pass user input values for controller just like hidden_field.